# How to write an api to fetch records of table based on index passed?

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a table(named sample) having some 100+ records and how can I write an api such that I want to fetch 'n' no of records as per index passed returning in json format,

for eg: if index=0 is passed i want to show first 0-5 records and for index=1 i want to show 6-10 records and so on.....

I have no idea to approach, but i am trying to fetch the index no. of records:

```
@app.route("/rows/<index>",methods=['GET'])
def getrecords():
    records=sample.query.filter()[:index] # which would return top index no of records
```

got mute on how to fetch records based on index(as explained above )....any help is appreciated!!

I am looking for something like, if `<index>=0` is passed then return a json of 0 to 5 records and if `<index>=5` is passed then return a json of 6 to 10 and so on.....

This is actually asked for pagination ,but i need to see whether it works with (POSTMAN)

Comment: @AndrewAllen This is different from what i asked mate, it's true i am using this for pagination , but i reffered that answer no clue yet

Comment: The redirected answer doesn't give exact solution , How can i just check through postman if it works!!.......??

Comment: I personally use [marshallow-SQLAlchemy](https://marshmallow-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to convert to json and return `jsonify(data), status_code` where status_code is say 200 or 201

Comment: yeah i knew this, but how I am thoughtless on how to achieve that index thing mentioned in question....any idea?

Comment: `@app.route('/rows/<int:index>')
def page(index):
    record_query = sample.query.paginate(index, 5, False)
    record_items = record_query.items
    return `yourschema`.jsonify(record_items)`....................If someone looking for answer!!